# How to order a list of tuples based on a relationship between the elements of said tuple

Tags: python, list, tree, tuples

I have the following list of tuples (where each number represents an individual)

```
relation = [(0,6),(1,2),(1,4),(1,6),(3,0),(3,4),(5,1),(7,0),(7,1)]
```

The tuple `(a,b)` means that the individual `a` is older than the individual `b`.

I need to find a way to order the individuals from the oldest to the youngest, and I have no clue how to do it. I think I should use trees for this problem, but I'm not really sure.

Tank you four your answers and help!

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You've been thinking in the right direction. Actually, you can solve the problem by modelling the input as a graph. Once this is done, the problem can be solved using topological sort.

```py
from collections import defaultdict, deque

def find_order(relation):

    # make graph
    young_to_old = defaultdict(set)
    persons = set()
    for older, younger in relation:
        young_to_old[younger].add(older)
        persons.add(younger)
        persons.add(older)

    # persons w/o an older person
    without_older = deque([p for p in persons if p not in young_to_old])

    # complementary data structure for faster lookups
    old_to_young = defaultdict(set)
    for younger, olders in young_to_old.items():
        for o in olders:
            old_to_young[o].add(younger)

    # topological sort
    result = []
    while without_older:
         p = without_older.popleft()
         result.append(p)
         for y in old_to_young[p]:
              young_to_old[y].remove(p)
              if not young_to_old[y]:
                   without_older.append(y)

    # check for cycle, no solution 
    if len(result) < len(young_to_old):
         return []

    return result
```

Then with your input:

```py
find_order(relation)
[3, 5, 7, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

You can for instance use a depth first traversal to perform this sorting:

```
def topsort(relation):
    # Create node list
    nodes = {node: [] for pair in relation for node in pair}

    # Create edges in reversed direction, as adjacency list
    for older, younger in relation:
        nodes[younger].append(older)

    result = []

    def visit(node):
        olders = nodes[node]
        if olders == 2:  # Already visited
            return
        if olders == 1:  # Is on the current path
            raise ValueError("cycle detected")
        nodes[node] = 1
        for older in olders:
            visit(older)
        nodes[node] = 2
        result.append(node)
        
    # Start depth first traversal
    for node in nodes:
        visit(node)

    return result

relation = [(0,6),(1,2),(1,4),(1,6),(3,0),(3,4),(5,1),(7,0),(7,1)]
print(topsort(relation))  # [3, 7, 0, 5, 1, 6, 2, 4]
```

Be aware that there can be multiple solutions. For instance, for this example input it is not known whether person #5 is older than person #7, so you can sort them either way.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It's really been helpful.

I've been reading your code, and I think I understand it, but i can't figure out how to modify it in order for it to print all the possible orders (following the example you wrote at the end, one order would be with 5 being older than 7 and another one would be with 7 being older than 5)

Comment: That would be a different question, and will require a different algorithm. If you draw the graph, you can see that several pairs exist for which the order is undefined. This can lead to many possible solutions. You'll need to use recursion. Have a go at it, and if you cannot find a solution, then ask a new question about this specifically.